# "or" tag on mobile while searching?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search, mobile-web

When I search for questions in my favorite tags (`intags:mine`),  it tells me that the results are tagged with "python or python-2.7 or ...".  The word "or" shows up (in all cases) as if it is another tag.  If I click it, it leads me to the "All Questions" page.  It seems to me that, as it isn't a tag, it shouldn't show up as one.  **Edit**: in case it isn't clear from the title, I see this only on mobile: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: "or" doesn't seems formated as tag, and I am sure that it's treated as logical operator.

Comment: @Braiam: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear.  This happens only on mobile.  I have added a screenshot.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you see when I search questions by tags. Would you please provide a URL link showing this search/results? Thanks!

Comment: @PetahChristian: Hm, the only link that reproduces it for me is [intags:mine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+is%3Aq) (with or without `is:q`).  I can't search `intags:5827958` (it just gives me all questions).  If I search with `infavorites:5827958`, it doesn't give a list of tags.  If I search for something like `[python] OR [python-2.7]`, the "or" shows up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mobile-specific path to rendering tags, and it wasn't taking account of "or" and "and" which should be excluded from normal tag rendering.

I have updated that code path, so things are more consistent between mobile and full site views.

With you in the next build.